# Stream's capacity vs length

Tags: c#, stream, copy, memorystream, capacity

When I write some stream into a new memory stream, the length and capacity of the memory stream are both set to 0 at first, and grow along with the write process. but at some point the capacity grows faster than the length.
After the write operation is done I get the correct length (Same as the original input stream's length), but with MUCH bigger capacity.
Is it correct?
Shouldn't they be the same?
I couldn't find any info about it

Comment: If you hit this searching for info on `List<T>` Capacity vs. Count - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485139/list-capacity-returns-more-items-than-added

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Shouldn't they be the same?

No - or at least, not necessarily. This is basically the same as a `List<T>`'s capacity vs its count (or `StringBuilder` for that matter). The idea is that in order to minimize the number of times you make a copy, when you need to increase your capacity, you increase it significantly - not just by one byte at a time. So for example, one strategy would be "Minimum of 16 bytes, and double the capacity when you need to."

After you've done some write operations, how is the stream meant to know that you're finished? And would you really want it to have to copy the entire contents in order to perform a write of one more byte?

Basically the trade-off is memory vs speed: the larger you make the capacity, the more writing you can do quickly between copies.

Comment: My buffer size is 8192, so after each "Write" inside the while loop length becomes 8192, then 16384, and so on. the capacity first goes 8192, 16384, etc, but in some point they stop growing at the same rate

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So do I need to set it in advance or just keep it this way?

Comment: @user990635: Well yes - I wouldn't be surprised if the capacity doubled each time you went over the capacity. So after 3 writes you might have a length of 24K and a capacity of 32K. Then the fourth write doesn't require any more capacity, so it's quicker and you end up with a length of 32K and a capacity of 32K. Then the *fifth* write needs more capacity, so it might double - giving a length of 40K and a capacity of 64K. You've then got three more writes which don't require the copy.

Comment: @user990635: If you know how much data you're going to write, make that the initial capacity. If you don't, just let it manage it itself - that will be less efficient in both space and time, but it should still *work*.

Comment: I know the length of the input stream (that I'm copying) so this will go well as capacity, right?

Comment: @user990635: Yes, exactly. That way the capacity and the length of your `MemoryStream` *should* be the same at the end.