# Generic list adds null values in c#

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a generic list called connectedEntites and I add items to this list in a for loop. I do a null check before adding. But even then whenever an item is added to this `List<>` a null value is also added. I did debug but there is noway a null value can be added. Due to this null value when i perform read operation the program crashes (as this is a COM program).

Below is the code for the class

```
public class EntityDetails
{
    public ObjectId objId { get; set; }
    public Handle objHandle { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        EntityDetails objAsEntityDetails = obj as EntityDetails;
        if (objAsEntityDetails == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsEntityDetails);
    }

    public bool Equals(EntityDetails other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return (this.objId.Equals(other.objId));
    }
}`
```

Below is the image where you can see the null values and the capacity also doubles as the item is added, but the count shows correct value.

[image: Generic List in Debug Mode]

Comment: `Count` says _2_ not _4_.  _[Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Comment: Yes it says 2. But why the null values?

Comment: The null values are in the internal array that the List uses. It's an implementation detail that should be of no concern. In which way do you use the list to get an exception/crash? (And they are nulls, because that's the `default(EntityDetails)`)

Comment: @Santosh, .NET's `List<T>` uses an array behind the scenes to store your data, which initializes the "unused" positions to the type's default value. If your elements are objects, then the positions of the array that haven't yet been used will be `null`.

Comment: @Dirk I have a condition.Thats where it crashes if(connectedEntites.Count(i=>i.className.ToLower() == "circle") < 2)

Comment: @Santosh If that throws a NullRefException then it's because i.className is null. Enumerating a List will only return the "valid" items, not every item in the internal array.

Comment: You just see that array since you are using the debugger which even shows private members. Thats causing your confusion. Normally you don't see and can't access the internal array used to store the items. It doubles it's capacity since allocating a new array is a relative expensive operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal structure of a `List<>` is an array and arrays have a specified length. This array needs to grow each time you fill it up by adding items to the `List<>`. The `Capacity` is the actual length of the internal array and is always automatically increased when the `Count` after adding equals the current `Capacity`. It doubles each time it does so.

If your COM application cannot handle the null values in the internal structure (i.e. the array) of the `List<EntityDetails>` you can use `TrimExcess()` to delete those reserved spaces.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds
>   Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by
>   automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old
>   elements and adding the new elements.

See also this question: [List<> Capacity returns more items than added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485139/list-capacity-has-more-items-than-added)